# Formulário não envia todas as variáveis pelo POST

Tags: php, formulário

Sou iniciante em PHP e criei um formulário, e quando submeto ele pelo `POST`, apenas duas variaveis (`DESCRICAO` e `CODIGO`) estão sendo enviadas, as demais ficam em branco. Qual é o erro nesse código?

```
<form action="../function/func_inserir.php" id="inserir_C" name="inserir_C"
    onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
<p style="margin-left:200px"><b>Descrição:</b>
<input type="text" name="DESCRICAO" MAXLENGTH="100" size="50" value="" />
<div id="Produto">
<p id="TABELAS"><b>PRODUTO</b></p>
<table id="TABELAS" >
 <tr>
   <th>Código do Produto:</th>
   <td>
      <input type="text" name="CODIGO" MAXLENGTH="13" size="11" value="" onkeypress="return Only_N(event)"/>
  </td>
  <th>Acabamento:</th>
  <td>
   <?php 
       $rs = mysql_query("SELECT ACABPK,DESCRICAO FROM dober.acabamento ORDER BY FAT"); 
       montaCombo('AC_cmb', $rs, 'ACABPK', 'DESCRICAO');
   ?>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Peso Bruto:</th>
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="PBRT" MAXLENGTH="7"  size="11" value="" onkeypress="return validate_P(event)"/>
    </td>
    <th> Tratamento Térmico:</th>
    <td>
    <?php 
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT TRAT_TERMPK,DESCRICAO FROM dober.tratamento_termico ORDER BY DESCRICAO"); 
        montaCombo('TT_cmb', $rs, 'TRAT_TERMPK', 'DESCRICAO');
    ?>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th>Peso Liquido:</th>
   <td>
      <input type="text" name="PLIQ" MAXLENGTH="7"  size="11" value="" onkeypress="return validate_P(event)"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div><!-- end of div produto -->

<div>               
<button type="submit" id="cadastra" class="btnCD">CADASTRAR</button>
<input type="hidden" name="OPCAO" value="insert" />
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: posta o código do seu `../function/func_inserir.php`

Comment: Olá amigo posta o arquivo que você recebe o formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei a seguinte página `func_inserir.php` e funcionou para essa variável:

```
<?php

$a = $_REQUEST['PLIQ'];

print $a;
```

Tenta capturar os valores via `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Gustavo, obrigado pela resposta, estava usando o str_replace para substituir valores em branco na variavel, por isso estava ficando tudo em branco, mesmo o $_POST com valor, ele ficava em branco. Abaixo um exemplo de como estava usando:$MQ2 = str_replace($_POST['MQ_cmb2'],'','99');